# how to create an QuantFig using cufflinks with iplot in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, plotly

```
import ipywidgets as wd
import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from plotly.offline import iplot,init_notebook_mode
from ipywidgets import interact,interact_manual
init_notebook_mode()

stocks=['QQQ','MSFT','GOOGL','FB','TSLA','AAPL']
indicators=['Bollinger Bands','MACD','RSI']

def ta_dashboard(asset,indicator,start_date,end_date,bb_k,bb_n,macd_fast,macd_slow,macd_signal,rsi_periods,rsi_upper,rsi_lower):
    df=yf.download(asset,start=start_date,end=end_date,progress=False,auto_adjust=True)
    qf=cf.QuantFig(df,title=f'TA Dashboard={asset}',legend='right',name=f'{asset}')
    if 'Bollinger Bands' in indicator:
        qf.add_bollinger_bands(periods=bb_n,boll_std=bb_k)
    if 'MACD' in indicator:
        qf.add_macd(fast_period=macd_fast,slow_period=macd_slow,signal_period=macd_signal)
    if 'RSI' in indicator:
        qf.add_rsi(period=rsi_periods,rsi_upper=rsi_upper,rsi_lower=rsi_lower,showbands=True)
    return qf.iplot()


controls_dict={'asset':stocks_selector,
               'indicator':indicator_selector,
               'start_date':start_date_selector,
               'end_date':end_date_selector,
               'bb_k':k_param,
               'bb_n':n_param,
               'macd_fast':macd_fast,
               'macd_slow':macd_slow,
               'macd_signal':macd_signal,
               'rsi_periods':rsi_period,
               'rsi_upper':rsi_upper,
               'rsi_lower':rsi_lower}

ui=wd.HBox([main_selector_box,secondary_selector_box])
out=wd.interactive_output(ta_dashboard,controls_dict)
```

I got the error message:
`PlotlyRequestError: Authentication credentials were not provided` which point to return qf.plot() part

I saw some post on stackoverflow says change iplot() to fig.show()
I want to change it to qf.show() but got another error qf don't have show()
what can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

I notice this in recent github issue in cufflink respository.

**Add cf.go_offline() help to solve the problem** because now it have offline mode and online mode

I change it to

```
    def ta_dashboard(asset,indicator,start_date,end_date,bb_k,bb_n,macd_fast,macd_slow,macd_signal,rsi_periods,rsi_upper,rsi_lower):
            cf.go_offline()
df=yf.download(asset,start=start_date,end=end_date,progress=False,auto_adjust=True)

    qf=cf.QuantFig(df,title=f'TA Dashboard={asset}',legend='right',name=f'{asset}')
    if 'Bollinger Bands' in indicator:
        qf.add_bollinger_bands(periods=bb_n,boll_std=bb_k)
    if 'MACD' in indicator:
        qf.add_macd(fast_period=macd_fast,slow_period=macd_slow,signal_period=macd_signal)
    if 'RSI' in indicator:
        qf.add_rsi(period=rsi_periods,rsi_upper=rsi_upper,rsi_lower=rsi_lower,showbands=True)
    return qf.iplot()
```

and it works

From Cufflinks github issue: https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/issues/267

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).